# Contrast between useEffect callback execution between v16 & v18 of react, what is the intended behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I have upgraded to react 18, ever since that I started to see a potential problem. Please take a look at following links where I have implemented the same app in two different versions.

React 16: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-8-0-forked-5pyqvg?file=/src/index.js

React 18: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-moore-9yb0xk?file=/src/index.js

As you can see I'm attaching a click listener to document. In React 16 version when we click, as expected, it is logging the previous state value, but in React 18 somehow React is able to identify the updated state value and logging the current value. Out of both which should be the intended behavior and how it is better than the other way?

Comment: I don't know what you are looking at but I see the same behavior in both sandboxes and they both work as I'd expect. There is no stale closure over the `counter` state since the `useEffect` hook is cleaning up the effect from the precious render cycle and adding a new click listener with the current state value.

Comment: @DrewReese the question is all about that only. Got the answer. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: I'm just pointing out that whatever you think the issue is and are asking about isn't reproducible in either of the codesandboxes you linked. Since there's no [mcve] in the question it's anyone's guess as to what your *actual* code is doing.

Comment: @DrewReese isn't React 16 showing 0 as first log and React 18 showing 1?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean and what is happening here now. The button's click event is propagating up the DOM and triggers the document's `onClick` handler as well, *before* the React state update has been processed. It's not a stale closure issue though. If you don't want to trigger additional event handlers higher in the DOMtree then simply call `.stopPropagation()` on the event object in the button's `onClick` handler.

Comment: @DrewReese But that will stop the log altogether right? We want the listener to run. But in 16 it runs with previous value and in 18 it runs with new value (that was the OPs question).

Comment: @TusharShahi I guess that's the point, the log probably shouldn't have happened to begin with. I can't speak for the OP and what they want or why, but why would anyone want ***two*** click handlers to fire simultaneously? I think most people would only expect the document listener to fire if an element was clicked that wasn't already expecting to handle its own click event. If the button is clicked then only the handler there should do anything. It's not a stale closure problem, it's an extraneous click handling problem. Does this make sense?

Comment: In my thinking the click handler was an abstraction of something more complex. I do not think the OP had a problem with both listeners running. Acc. to me it is still a question of different behaviours. And although I agree that closure was probably not real issue here but the order of effects and event handlers definitely caused confusion.

Comment: @TusharShahi If the OP's "abstraction" isn't click handlers and bubbling DOM events then I don't suspect there'd be much issue. Who knows? ‍♂️ We can only answer to the OP's current contrived code examples. I agree, the underlying issue seems to be with a misunderstanding of the component lifecycle and DOM event handling.

Comment: @DrewReese there isn't any misunderstanding, the only ask here is how come the same code with same framework but different versions is different. This question is all about to understand the contrast between useEffect callback execution between v16 & v18 of react.

Comment: I see now. Basically in `react@17` React fundamentally overhauled how and where DOM events handlers are attached and processed. See [Changes to Event Delegation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#changes-to-event-delegation). The `useEffect` hook isn't an integral part of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot comment on what the intended behaviour is. I would assume the behaviour of any package in a newer version would be the intended one.

For me personally, the behaviour in React 18 makes more sense. I do not think I would want to run my listener with an older value. But this is my opinion.

Points to recall before reading the rest of the answer:

**1. React cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.**

**2. A discrete input is a type of event where the result of one event can affect the behaviour of the next, like clicks or presses.**

The main reason you see this behaviour is because  the `useEffect` callback is running before your event listener in React 18. So before the event listener from the first `useEffect` runs, it is removed because of the cleanup and a new event listener is attached. This listener has the updated (correct) value of state.

Look at the logs in these 2 sandboxes: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-8-0-forked-926465?file=/src/components/App.js), [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-stitch-jrisum?file=/src/App.js).

The callback for useEffect runs before the Document event listener itself in React 18 (but not in React 16). The closure with old value does not exist in the case of React 18.

The order in React 16 is:

1. button click event
2. rerender (because of state udpate)
3. event listener code
4. cleanup (from previous useEffect)
5. new useEffect (attaches new event listener)

Contrast this with React 18:

1. button click event
2. rerender (because of state udpate)
3. cleanup (from previous useEffect)
4. new useEffect (attaches new event listener)
5. new event listener code

Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/128)
The very example mentioned in the thread is of a counter.

**TLDR:**

> In React 18, useEffect fires synchronously when it's the result of a discrete input. For example, if useEffect attaches an event listener, the listener is guaranteed to be added before the next input.

Some comments from the thread:

In React 17 and below, the function passed to `useEffect` typically fires asynchronously after the browser has painted. The idea is to defer as much work as possible until paint so that the user experience is not delayed. However, although passive effects do not block the browser from painting, they need to fire before the next discrete input event, so that the result can be observed by the event system. (Like in this case where we need to log the correct count value)

**Note:** The above behaviour is still different than [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) because it does not block the main thread (which would block the render).

Comment: the same behaviour is reflected in react 17 as well. Only in react 16 the (potential) intended behaviour is happening.

Comment: To be clear: Is your intended behaviour that the value be stale? I saw a comment that in React 17 also they might backport this, so they probably fixed it there too.

Comment: It’s not precisely like I want the stale value, but I feel like places where we used this behaviour to achieve something might start failing when we upgrade to v18.

Comment: The React team clearly mentions that this is the more consistent behaviour. So according to them, this is how it is gonna be in future.

Comment: Tip: You can listen to the event in capture phase. If the above  example is a true representation of your issue: `    document.addEventListener("click", listener,true);`. This way even before the effect runs, the click will be handled. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-violet-vdeb97?file=/src/App.js

Comment: *the same behaviour is reflected in react 17 as well.* I think you are wrong here, I just checked and it looks like in React17 it has the same behaviour as React16

Comment: v17.2.0 and thanks for the tip.

Comment: Will take a look at 17.2.0. Event starts with capture phase where it goes from document first to button. If you call the event in capture phase then the button event listener would not have been called and in that case button event listener would not have been triggered meaning state would not have updated, effect would not run etc, so your document listener runs with old value. In bubble phase (default), event bubbles up from button to document. So first event listener for button is called which updates the state and the flow described in the answer happens. You can read up on this.

Comment: well now this really makes sense. Such a brilliant use of capturing phase. Accepting this as answer.